# Mercurial batch rename to change file types

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Dumb thing, we are changing our code standard that all C++ header files need to be ".hpp" instead of ".h" (leaving .h to be C compatible headers). So my library only has *.h files in it. Is there a quick way built in to mercurial to do this rename or do I need to write my own script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial has a way to do it if you want to rename them in all revisions back to the start of time (and thus change history and invalidate any clones), but since you probably don't want do  do that you can just do:

```
for thefile in $(find $(hg root) -name '*.h') ; do hg rename $thefile ${thefile}pp ; done
```